# Is there a word in English for copy which is better than the original

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to use that word to talk about the cover songs which are better than the original songs.

Edit: Thanks for the answers. However, I am specifically looking for a single word replacement for "a copy which is better than the original."

Comment: **impossible!**

Comment: I think "better than the original" is what you're looking for.

Comment: @HotLicks but I was thinking may there was like a single word for that.

Comment: You found it: ***better***. [*17 Cover Songs That Are Way Better Than The Original*](http://www.businessinsider.com/17-cover-songs-better-than-the-original-2013-10)

Comment: Just a comment:  all these answers are giving you synonyms for *better*, not specifically *a copy which is better than the original*.

Comment: Incidentally, the answer is also useful for dvdrips, which are generally higher quality (fixing telecine errors, etc.) than the originals.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry [Are you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zqv808Yovg8) [sure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWVWCupCB-8)?

Comment: @Lohoris - name one!

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I… just did. Follow the links.

Comment: The answer to your edit: **there isn't one**.

Comment: genetically-modified

Answer (score 14):

For a noun, which seems to be what you are looking for, try **improvement**, e.g. "Of the three covers we heard tonight, only two were improvements on the original songs."

Answer (score 10):

> **[surpass](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/surpass)** sur·pass  /sərˈpas/
>   **1.** exceed; be greater than. be better than.

alternative synonyms:  *transcend*; *outdo*; *outshine*; *outclass*; *improve on*; *top*; *trump*;  *better*.

> The cover **outshines** the original (etc.)

The following search: [cover song "outshines the original"](https://www.google.it/search?q=the%20cover%20outshines&oq=the%20cover%20outshines&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6978j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=cover%20song%20%22outshine%20the%20original%22&start=0) on Google produced a respectable 82,300 results. It is nowhere high a number as "[be better than](https://www.google.it/search?q=the%20cover%20outshines&oq=the%20cover%20outshines&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6978j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=cover%20song%20%22better%20than%20the%20original%22&start=20)" (26,800,000 results) but the OP asked for a snappier one word expression, the term *outshine* is not only shorter but it is more striking and less cliché.

Comment: I think **outdo** could be highlighted in this answer too.

Comment: @mungflesh the (etc.) is meant to imply that any of the synonyms can apply. I quite like *tops the original* and [***trumps the original***](https://www.google.it/search?q=trump&oq=trump&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=cover+%22trumps+the+original%22&start=10) too.

Answer (score 3):

To *be better than* something is to ***[eclipse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eclipse)*** it, depriving it of significance:

> Jill's cover of *Nothing Else Matters* ***eclipses*** the original.

Also see: [best](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/best), [trounce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trounce), [upstage](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/upstage)

Answer (score 2):

A useful word to describe this concept is *supersede*, though I would use it carefully when talking about music. Some songs do supersede the original version, Santana's, *She's Not There*, as at the time it was a very modern version compared to the original and is frequently regarded as his song , but certain purists would be horified at that notion.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the word "refine", as in the cover songs **refine** the originals or (if you need a noun) are **refinements** of the originals.

From the [Mirriam-Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refine) - "Refine: to improve (something) by making small changes"

Answer (score 1):

**transcendent**; adjective, tran·scen·dent -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcendent)

> a :  exceeding usual limits :  surpassing
>      b :  extending or lying beyond the limits of ordinary experience

Johnny Cash's rendition of *Hurt* is **transcendent**; I can't stand Reznor's voice (just an example, the reverse is actually true for me).

Or you could say:

Johnny Cash's rendition of *Hurt* is **[better than the original copy]**; I can't stand Reznor's voice.

Comment: That's the only better word I got for *better than what was*.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of music, "outperforms" would be an interesting variant of 'surpasses'. ("Band A's cover of The Song outperformed Band B's original in every way.")

Or, perhaps, "overshadows" (especially if the original song was by Cliff Richard and the, err, Shadows).

Answer (score 0):

All of the phrases provided above are just that -- phrases, and there are nuances to the different verbs that people suggest (supersede, scale, transcend, eclipse). But no, there is no single word in English that means "a copy that is better than the original." Given all the clunky phrases suggested, I think we need one. Maybe you could create it?

Comment: do you have a suggestion for one?

Answer (score -2):

This phrase may be used to express the same idea:

> He made it his own.

Comment: This is not a single word, which has been specifically requested. Also, you do not explain why this is a good answer. As far as I can see, it is not.

Comment: Not only is this not a single word, so not an answer to the question, it is also not relevant to the question as far as I can tell. To make something ones own does not imply any copy; be it better or worse than the original.

Answer (score -5):

You can also say-

- The cover song **[scored over](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/score)** the original.

Comment: If someone said a cover "scaled" the original, I'd reply, "What do you mean?"